# IntelliJ IDEA with Git remember author

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ with a Git project, and have setup my `user.name` and `user.email` properly. The problem is when committing using the IDE interface the author is not selected by default. I can click and I get a dropdown to select it, but sometimes I forget to do that, and it's a pain to ammend the commit each time I forget.

Is there a way to set the author automatically on commit, since it's only one, and it would save me some headaches?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't pre-select author in the combobox which is a [known cosmetic issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63926), however it should use the author defined in the git configuration by default.

Please double check that `user.name` and `user.email` is specified properly in the global git configuration.

Some users mentioned a problem when using cygwin git, when IDEA probably cannot find the global git config. In this case it may help if you specify the user for the local project configuration:

```
git config --local user.name "John Doe"
git config --local user.email john@doe.com
```

Comment: You are indeed right, if I don't select anything there, the commit will have the right user. I was afraid of leaving it like that since I didn't want to risk pushing it without an author, which would have been harder to fix.

Comment: Is there any way to edit / amend the IntelliJ author list?

Comment: @MartinHaeberli: I see at least one place the author strings are stored in one's project directory: `.idea/workspace.xml`. Removing an email address from was reflected in the drop down for Git Author in Commit Changes dialog.

Comment: `git config --local user.name` to return/get the value of `user.name`

Comment: For me this doesn't work. I don't know what IntelliJ uses as logic for the default selection, but it seems to take my global config over my local one. I can't see any way in the UX to select a default author and the git config has no effect

Comment: IntelliJ just calls git commit and lets git itself decide on the author info, unless the author field is filled up with something. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60999725/7523979

Answer (score 20):

Go to your project where git is **initialized**.

Then enable the hidden folders and find "`.git`" and go inside the folder.

Find the file called "`config`" and add below code and save.

```
[user]
      name = username
      email = username@domaim.com
```

Enter your correct username and email accordingly. This will be picked permanently and you do not need to change again.

Comment: `git config -e --local` is probably the safer way to do that

Answer (score 1):

Open the Terminal and execute one of the following commands:

To set a name for every Git repository on your machine, use `$ git config --global user.name "John Smith"`

To set a name for a single repository, use `$ git config user.name "John Smith"`

[Go to JetBrains Git Page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/commit-and-push-changes.html)

***This will change the upcoming changes you submit on GitHub but won't change the username which you have committed earlier***.

[image: Snapshot of IntelliJ]