# Global git config Intellij

Tags: git, ubuntu, intellij-idea, version-control

I am using the latest version of Intellij IDEA 2019.3 on Ubuntu 18.04 and whenever I create a new project I have to add a local git config because Intellij cannot find the global config. From the IDEA terminal git can read my global git settings but IDEA VCS can't.

Comment: Does https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-131645 look like your case?

Comment: Yes it looks like it solved it for me. I had to edit ~/.gitconfig file. I guess git was using a different config file. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @CrazyCoder do you want to add it as an answer or should I remove the question?

Comment: It's actually not clear how the linked issue has helped since it states that it's not supported while you verified that editing `~/.gitconfig` works. The linked issue is obsolete probably?

Comment: It might have been patched I guess.

Comment: The mentioned request is to cache the config for the purpose of UI. it does not mean that commands called by IDEA ignore global config. git client called by IDEA should read all its configs on its own.

Comment: This is where visual studio is better than intellij.  Visual Studio allow u to set Git configuration globally(not locally) via a dialog box.  Such that in future, all future projects would use that global settings

Comment: Who cares about Visual Studio? This question was about Intellij.

Comment: Also, Visual Studio does not run on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ does not have builtin git and thus is not looking for configs itself - it just issues commands to the command-line git client, and git itself reads the configs as needed and applies them.

The only reason for git to see a config when started manually, but not see when started by the IDE could be environmental differences - e.g. if you have some environment variable altering gitconfig (e.g. `$GIT_CONFIG` or `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`), which was set in the current tty, but is not available in the IDE context.

Using the default global config file `~/.gitconfig` should always work though

Comment: This is not true at all (for OSx at least). IntelliJ Idea does not respect your git config. For example: if you were to add a `branch ["master"] \n pushRemote = no_push` to your `.gitconfig` IntelliJ will still push to master if you push through the GUI. However, doing it yourself via the CLI will result in a failed to push message.

Comment: IntelliJ Idea will overwrite your `~/.gitconfig` with whatever is in your `PROJECT/.git/config`.